# Python Automatically Back up Files to Google Drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, shutil

I am currently planning to automatically back up files to Google Drive like this:
1. Create a script to do the job:

```
import glob, os, shutil
src = r'/Users/me'
dst = r'/Users/me/Google Drive/Code'

files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, "*.ipynb"))
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.copy2(file, dst)
```

2. Transform my scrip into an app using py2app (not yet attempted).
3. Use Automator to run the .app file periodically.

The problem I'm currently facing in step 1 is that when files get copied to the Google Drive folder, they are **"black listed."**

Is this even a good approach? I feel like there is a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: define back-listed

Comment: I can't. I just know that it indicates a problem with syncing.

Comment: where does it say they are black listed?

Answer (score 0):

I tried again and it worked (Google Drive icon at top right - clicked on view non-synced files - then selected "retry..."